# assigned in python considered as a copy of an object

Tags: python, object, bubble-sort

I don't understand the reason that in the first example, `b` is considered as a copy of `a` and it will change with `a` but not in the second example

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp
    return  alist

a=[3,2,1]
b=a
a=bubbleSort(a)
print(a)
print(b)
```

**The output:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]

a=[3,2,1]
b=a
a=[1,2,3]

print(a)
print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: BTW, please don't use Code Snippets for Python code, they only work with code that can run in a Web browser: HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

Comment: Hint: in your first example, `b` is not "a copy of a" - `a` and `b` are two names pointing at the same object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a=[3,2,1]
b=a # **here you're refrencing by memory not value**
a=bubbleSort(a)

print id(a) 
print id(b)

# these both will give you same memory reference

print(a)
print(b)
```

In the second example when you're doing `b=a` you're referencing by memory, but when you did `a=[1,2,3]` you're associating `a` to a new memory reference `b` is still bound to the old one.

```
a = [3,2,1]
b=a

print id(b) #4376879184
print id(a) #4376879184


#they will be having the same id

a = [1,2,3]
#now you have assigned a new address which will have the new array

print id(b) #4376879184
print id(a) #4377341464
#they will be having different id now
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example - You send the 'reference' to the list which is shared between a and b (and change it).

In the second example - You explicitly change the 'reference' when stating a = [1,2,3]

If you want to fix this, return a different instance from the bubble sort function (Dont change the actual list being sent, create a new one and return it - this is a thing you do with pointers in C, less in python).

Either way read up a bit on mutable / immutable types in python - https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747 (First result on google).